# How to make the calculate button work

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have this code that I'm working on, but the calculate button won't work no matter what I do. I want to find the cost per square inch using the pizzaSize and pizzaCost. How can I make the calculate button actually calculate?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Pizza Calculator </title>
<script src="pizzaCalc.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pizza Calculator</h1>
<p>
<label for="priceBox">Cost: </label><input type="text" id="priceBox" size="5"/></p>
<p>
    <label for="sizeBox">Diameter :</label><input type="text" id="sizeBox"     
    size="5"/>
</p>
<input type="button" id="cpsi" value="Cost PSI" onclick="calculate(cpsi)">

</body>
</html>

"use strict"
function pizzaCalc () {
    var size = document.getElementById ("sizeBox").value;
    size = parseFloat (size);
    var price = document.getElementById("priceBox").value;
    price = parceFloat (price);
    var costPerSquareInch = price / (3.14 * (size / 2)^2)
    alert('Pizza value :' +costPerSquareInch);
    document.getElementById("cpsi").value = costPerSquareInch;
}
```

Comment: where is the code for `pizzaCalc.js`?

Comment: show js code if u want help otherwise theres no way we can help you

Comment: I don't see any code. There is only HTML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Pizza Calculator </title>
<script src="pizzaCalc.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pizza Calculator</h1>
<p>
<label for="priceBox">Cost: </label><input type="text" id="priceBox" value="5"/></p>
<p>
    <label for="sizeBox">Diameter :</label><input type="text" id="sizeBox" value="5"/>
</p>
<input type="button" id="cpsi" value="Cost PSI" onclick="pizzaCalc()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict"
    function pizzaCalc () {
    var size = document.getElementById ("sizeBox").value;
    size = parseFloat (size);
    var price = document.getElementById("priceBox").value;
    price = parseFloat (price);
    var costPerSquareInch = price / (3.14 * (size / 2)^2)
    alert('Pizza value :' +costPerSquareInch);
    document.getElementById("cpsi").value = costPerSquareInch;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It appears that

```
<input type="button" id="cpsi" value="Cost PSI" onclick="calculate(cpsi)">
```

should be

```
<input type="button" id="cpsi" value="Cost PSI" onclick="pizzaCalc()">
```

also I am assuming **size** should be **value** on the input tags.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' >
<title> Pizza Calculator </title>
<script src="pizzaCalc.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pizza Calculator</h1>
<p>
<label for="priceBox">Cost: </label><input type="text" id="priceBox" value="5"/></p>
<p>
    <label for="sizeBox">Diameter :</label><input type="text" id="sizeBox" value="5"/>
</p>
<input type="button" id="cpsi" value="Cost PSI" onclick="pizzaCalc()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict"
    function pizzaCalc () {
    var size = document.getElementById ("sizeBox").value;
    size = parseFloat (size);
    var price = document.getElementById("priceBox").value;
    price = parseFloat (price);
    var costPerSquareInch = price / (3.14 * (size / 2)^2)
    alert('Pizza value :' +costPerSquareInch);
    document.getElementById("cpsi").value = costPerSquareInch;
```

Comment: There is a formatting problem in your post, the code is not complete. Also add some explanation with it.